# Address Sanitizer version mismatch cmake c++

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I'm trying to compile a program with address sanitizer, I've installed the C++ Address Sanitizer through Visual Studio Installer.

Compiler in use is - Clang 15.0.1 (MSVC CLI) for MSVC 17.5.33516.290 (Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64)

I get the following output -

```
PS C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\Desktop\Repos\horizon\build> cmake "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon/out/install/Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\clang-cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows -DWITH_TESTS=true -DWITHOUT_SERVERS=true "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=/MD /INFERASANLIBS /fsanitize=address" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=/MD /fsanitize=address" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=/MD /fsanitize=address" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=/MD /fsanitize=address" "-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=/MD /fsanitize=address" "-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=/MD /fsanitize=address" "-SC:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon" "-BC:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon/out/build/Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release"                                                             -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 15.0.1 with MSVC-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 15.0.1 with MSVC-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon/out/build/Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lpf77t

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_76616.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:m && MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET Framework

    lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __asan_init [C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\Desktop\Repos\horizon\out\build\Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-lpf77t\cmTC_76616.vcxproj]
      >>> referenced by cmTC_76616.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj:(asan.module_ctor)

    lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __asan_version_mismatch_check_v8 [C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\Desktop\Repos\horizon\out\build\Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-lpf77t\cmTC_76616.vcxproj]
      >>> referenced by cmTC_76616.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj:(asan.module_ctor)

    lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __asan_shadow_memory_dynamic_address [C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\Desktop\Repos\horizon\out\build\Tests-Clang-MSVC-Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-lpf77t\cmTC_76616.vcxproj]
      >>> referenced by cmTC_76616.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `clang-cl.exe` as compilers, when I should've been using the clang provided in the `GNU` CLI environment.